# Giving player extra hearts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way that I can give a player extra hearts? For example, if you've ever played mineplex hunger games, you know that you get 8 extra hearts to start out with. Is there anyway I can acheive this in vanilla minecraft? I want to make a map so that players permanently have extra hearts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `/effect` command works, but don't go too hardcore on the health or it will spam your screen.

But to clear it when you do, use `/effect @a clear`.

Comment: Oops, I already went hardcore with it and it crashed my game. Twice. :)

Comment: 1.13 syntax for last command: `/effect clear @a`

Answer (score 0):

I had solved my own question, just use this command:

```
/effect <player> 21 <duration> <amplifier>
```

Comment: @MechanicalBanana it says I have to wait two days to accept it.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect give <player> health_boost <duration> <amplifier>`

Answer (score -2):

use this as a template /effect  21 1000000 10

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  How does this differ from the other answers already here?